# I have problems after uninstalling jdk 7 on mac with rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk

Tags: java, macos

I have problems after uninstalling  jdk 7 on mac book pro with rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdkmajor.minor.macro[_update].jdk

I also have installed java 8 and Intellij works well. But any attempt to run java -version or mvn crashes with error:

dyld: could not load inserted library '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjsig.dylib' because image not found

[1]    1216 trace trap  mvn

And in the same time I can build all the projects with IntelliJ.

I even can't run vim - I have the same mistake.
So, my questions: 
1. What is the correct way to uninstall JDK?
2. What should I do in my situation to restore the system?

Comment: Can you show the output from `echo $JAVA_HOME`,`echo $PATH` and `echo $CLASSPATH`?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME shows an empty line

Comment: echo $PATH shows /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/andrew/globals/bin

Comment: echo $CLASSPATH shows /Users/andrew/globals/dev/java/lib/JDK16/globalsdb.jar

Comment: Good. The next step is to run `env | grep DYLD` and tell us what it finds.

Comment: env | grep DYLD
dyld: could not load inserted library '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjsig.dylib' because image not found

dyld: could not load inserted library '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjsig.dylib' because image not found

[1]    1370 trace trap  env |
       1371 trace trap  grep DYLD

Comment: OK, I see. Anything that's not a built-in command is trying to dynamically load a library, which does not exist... Try running `unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, and after that, try the `env | grep DYLD`.

Comment: Thank you! java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)

Comment: Can I uninstall this java and install jdk 8 instead?

Comment: So, as this was kind of what I gave in my answer, consider accepting it :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by mattias in his answer, your problem stems from a command in one of your bash startup files, that tells bash to load certain dynamic libraries before it attempts to run any command.

Using `unset DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` will only solve this **temporarily**, for the current running terminal. So you should fix the problem permanently, by first running that command, and then editing your `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files with `vim` or `nano`.

If you see a line that says

```
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjsig.dylib
```

just remove this line. If it inserts any additional libraries in addition to that libraries, just erase this particular library from `/Library` to `libsig.dylib` including the following `:` (if it's the last one, then the preceding `:`).

Exit Terminal, run it again and make sure your problem has been solved.

The procedure you have been following for removing the JDK is the correct one as suggested by Oracle. The problem was that once in the history of that machine, you or whoever was using it added that library to the `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` environment variable and this caused the problem. Also, the reason why this did not affect IntelliJ is that it is not running through `bash`, so `bash` commands do not affect it.

If you want to remove any other Java version, you should do the same as you did before, but make sure in advance that nothing in `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` refers to something inside `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in your .bash_profile and try to look for

```
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libSaturnFE.dylib
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
```

or anything similar. These might be causing the problem you experience.
Try commenting them out and reload your bash with

```
exec bash
```

and see if the problem persist.

Comment: exec bash brings dyld: could not load inserted library '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjsig.dylib' because image not found

Comment: Definitely sounds like something screwed up in your .bash_profile or perhaps .bashrc. Try review your .bash_profile for any oddities.